# How do I execute a Python script in Django using javascript

Tags: python, html, django

I have a python + electronJS + Djangao app. I am trying to launch a python script with a button click (from the HTML front end).

The app launches fine. But when I click the button to launch the python script from the HTML window, nothing happens (I get a blank HTML page).

Here is my java script file:

```
let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell')
var path = require("path")


function get_weather() {

  let pyshell = new PythonShell('Emotion-recognition-master/real_time_video.py', options);
  //let python = spawn('python', [path.join(__dirname, '/home/ironmantis7x/Documents/BSSTLLC/electronJS/electronpydemo1/python-app-with-electron-gui/engine/Emotion-recognition-master', 'real_time_video.py'), obsFilePath, navFilePath]);

  pyshell.on('message', function(message) {
    swal(message);
  })
  //document.getElementById("city").value = "";
}
```

Here is my HTML code for the gui launcher:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1><b><center>MAVERICK Sentry System</center></b></h1>
      <h3><i><center>by Maverick AI - a Saudi Company</center></i></h3>
      <br>
    <br>
    <center>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <img style="width:40%;padding:5px" src="images/weather-icon.png"/>
      <br>
      <button class="btn btn-info"><a style="color:white" href="weather.html">Weather</a></button>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
      <img style="width:40%;padding:5px" src="images/emotion_recognition.png"/>
      <br>
    <button class="btn btn-info"><a style="color:white;" href="real_time_video.py">Emotion Recognition</a></button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <img style="width:40%;padding:5px" src="images/text_recognition.png"/>
      <br>
    <button class="btn btn-info"><a style="color:white;" href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/detect">Text Recognition</a></button>
    </div>
    </center>
</div>
</div>
<body>
```

How can I run my python script from html button click properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to make sure the button sends a post request when clicked. For example, let's assume the button sends a post request to a url 'execute_script/'.

Then, urls.py should look like:

```
# route url to view function:
urlpatterns = [
    path('execute_script/', views.ExecuteScript, name='execute_script'),
]
```

And, view.py can look like:

```
def ExecuteScript(request):

    # unpack request if needed:
    some_data = request.POST['some_data']

    # execute some script here...    

    # pack context:
    context = json.dumps({
        'status' : 'Success',
    })

    # return an HTTP response with context:
    return HttpResponse(context)
```

Comment: I am not returning any data or output to the screen.
I am trying launching an opencv app from a button click.

Comment: in Django, view functions always need to return an HttpResponse, even if its empty. If the button click sends the post request to the url `'execute_script'` - then the `ExecuteScript` python function will be called. You can put any python script/code in this function.

Comment: Daniel: I will give this a try.

Comment: thanks Daniel. This answer was the closest. I had to do some other stuff to get it to work, but this was it.